# is there any algorithm with php5 to synchronize between locale and online databases?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have two databases online and local. I want to synchronize data between them. Is there any algorithm with PHP5 to do this ?

Comment: I'm assuming that by "locale", you actually mean "local"?

Comment: Yeah, it's called master-master replication and it has little to do with either [tag:symfony2] nor [tag:ajax] nor [tag:php].

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://www.phpmysqlsync.com/, this should output what you need to update the databases. It won't do it for you however.

It's also worth noting that PHP probably isn't the best route to go with this. PHPMyAdmin, will allow you to set up synchronisation. See [this blog post](http://toyhouse.cc/profiles/blogs/synchronize-databases-by-phpmyadmin) for more information.

I'm assuming that you're using MySQL, if you're using a different database type, please update your question.